# how to get a constant value by mathematica?

Tags: algebra, group-theory

I'm anew user of mathematica ,, forgive me

A.B - B.A = 2Ιf C and

c = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -Ι}, {0, Ι, 0}};
I is imaginary number, f is a constant and equal (1/2)

How to get the value of f by mathematica?**

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far? In case of homework, please add the homework tag. Your screenshot does not seem to offer any additional information, but a more careful description of your task would be in everyone's favor.

Comment: This is not a home work. the result of A.B-B.A is equal to the matrix c multiplied by imaginary number and a constant. from books the constant is equal 1/2 , but I want mathematica to identify it. I do not how to deal with mathematica, this is the first time of using it.

Answer (score 1):

I admit I am confused by the question. The image suggests the aim is to find `f` (a scalar) but f`->1 (not 1/2). I post this as motivation/clarification, e.g.

```
a = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
b = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
c = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -I}, {0, I, 0}};
Solve[(a.b - b.a) == f I c, f]
```

Note: `a.b-b.a` yields: `{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 0}}`

Comment: yes you are right, I forgot  that it is multiplied by 2 ,so f is equal 1/2
a.b - b.a =2 f I c............thank you very much that helped me